# Worklight Direct Update doesn't work when wlapp built outside of studio

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have a worklight i/OS hybrid application built and deployed to the worklight console using RTC jazz team build and the ant-builder ant tasks (6.1.0.1). The ipa packaging is done on a separate machine, though using the same level of Worklight Studio (6.1.0.1).

I've compared the wlapp files that are generated, and they are basically identical except for some whitespace characters (tabs, line feeds), probably due to the different environments (Windows vs AIX), and the following:

index.html

```
"WORKLIGHT_NATIVE_VERSION": "3921556017",
"WORKLIGHT_PLATFORM_VERSION": "6.1.0.01.20140311-2356",

"WORKLIGHT_NATIVE_VERSION": "1475155033",
"WORKLIGHT_PLATFORM_VERSION": "6.1.0.01.20140311-2356",
```

deployment.data

```
native=3921556017
native=1475155033
```

However, the direct update never happens when the wlapp is updated on the server.

on the WL.Client.connect call, the following json comes back as part of the response

gadgetProps":{"directUpdate":{},"ENVIRONMENT":"iphone"}

What are we missing here? What can be preventing the direct update from triggering?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6.1.0.1 iFix version 6.1.0.01.20140518-1532 from IBM Fix Central seems to have resolved this problem for us.

Comment: do you have the url of the iFix ?

Answer (score 0):

And what if you are not using ant, but rather built the project in Worklight Studio straight to Xcode from then install the .ipa and test Direct Update. Does it work?

From your question it is not clear whether or not you've confirmed one or the other.

Regardless, since the v6.1.0.1 build you are using, several Direct Update-related fixes were introduce; one with close proximity to the error you mention (directUpdate:{ }), so I suggest to to open a PMR in order to receive the latest available iFix (not yet available at IBM Fix Central).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - direct update does work when the build is done using studio alone on the same platform. However, it is not an option (at least not an acceptable option) to use studio to perform the team builds. Thx

I will see about opening a PMR - glad to hear it may be fixed.

Comment: Actually no fix that I know of regarding using ant in this usecase, but best to try.